# How do I determine what exception was thrown?

Tags: javascript, firefox, exception

I work on a script that is added to hundreds of different websites in ways that I can't always predict, particularly when code is loaded in an `iframe`. In my code I've got a try/catch block setup to handle the exceptions. It's something like this:

```
var vals = {};

try {
    vals.hostname = window.top.location.hostname; // will throw DOMException if loaded in iframe
    < more code which might throw other exceptions >
} catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof DOMException) {
        vals.hostname = window.location.hostname;
    } else {
        <do something different>
    }
}
```

`e instanceof DOMException` works awesome on Chrome, but it turns out that on Firefox and Safari, `e instanceof DOMException` is `false` on those browsers. I've done a lot of searching and for some reason can't seem to find anybody who explains how to check the exception type in a browser agnostic way.

Edit: Okay, Chrome is throwing a `DOMException`, but Firefox (and presumably Safari) are just throwing a generic "Error":

```
Error: Permission denied to access property "hostname"
```

I think that means I can't do anything with the specific error on other browsers.

Comment: Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: if the error thrown is an instance of DOMException, then Firefox will see it as such - perhaps the error thrown is not a DOMException - you can always `console.log(e)` to see what type of exception it is

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX. I'd done that before, but just saw the Error and didn't even notice that it wasn't a `DOMException`.